# How can I include cells from another notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter-lab

I am looking for a way to include one notebook in another, similar to LaTeX's [`\include`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project#Inputting_and_including_files) directive.

My goal is to split up one large notebook, that mixes Markdown and code cells, into smaller chunks for easier maintainability.

#### What I've tried

- I tried using `%run "other.ipynb"` command, but that only shows output of code cells and does not include the Markdown cells. So if I have:

```
In [1]: %run "other.ipynb"
```

```
In [1]: # This is a markdown cell
In [2]: Print("Simple string")
Out[2]: Simple string
```

The output when running `main.ipynb` is only `Simple string`, while I expected it to show the Markdown cell as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a code cell in `main.ipynb` that contains

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
import nbformat as nb

# Read the notebook file
with open('other.ipynb', 'r') as file:
    notebook = nb.read(file, nb.NO_CONVERT)

# Extract and display Markdown cells
for cell in notebook.cells:
    if cell.cell_type == 'markdown':
        markdown_text = ''.join(cell.source)
        display(Markdown(markdown_text))
```

which did what I wanted to achieve. It's not perfect in the sense that it would be nice to hide the importing code, but it's better than nothing.